# paid for ubuntu extra on paypal (twice I think) and it never brought me back

Tags: system-installation, downloads

I paid for ubuntu (the $16.00 - I think I paid twice) and it never brought me back. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Whom did you pay?

Comment: You donated...?

Comment: brought you back to where?

Comment: You don't pay for Ubuntu -- it is free.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We are not actually part of Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu), we are a community of volunteers. We have nothing to do with whatever money you paid to anyone. In any case, Ubuntu is free, if you paid something it was a donation, you can simply download Ubuntu directly.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is **free.**

It has been **free** since years.

It will forever be **free** as long as humanity rules here on planet Earth.

If you paid for it, and yet you never got one, it's a big sham. Report the seller to eBay or whichever site sold that to you immediately. In India, eBay and other sites hav an anti-fraud system that blocks payments to sellers till you sign a receipt for it with your courier. There might be something similar for your country as well.

But the thing is: **you should always consult the official website of the thing you're paying for.** Ubuntu is always free, whether you want the desktop, mobile, or server edition.

**EDIT:** Were you donating? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/